# Non primitive type attribute for custom directive

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I have a question regarding graphql schema definition.

Can one define a non-primitive type as an attribute for a directive? If yes, then what is the syntax when using the directive on a field?

Say for example that there is a Url type defined as follows:

```
type Url {
   address: String!
   desription: String
}
```

and a directive

```
@custom_directive { 
    url: Url!
} on FIELD_DEFINITION
```

How can one then use that directive on a field?

```
type AnotherType {
    field: SomeOtherType @custom_directive(url: ???)
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can define a non-scalar type as an attribute in directive , but it should be the `Input` type :

```
input UrlInput {
   address: String!
   desription: String
}
```

And you also miss the `directive` reserved word when declaring it. It should be:

```
directive @custom_directive (url:UrlInput!) on FIELD_DEFINITION
```

To annotate it on a field :

```
type AnotherType {
    field: SomeOtherType @custom_directive (url : {address: "foo" description: "bar"})
}
```

Given a `GraphQLSchema` , you can then access the directive value annotated on a given field by :

```java
    Map<String, Object> value  = (Map<String, Object>) graphQLSchema
       .getObjectType("AnotherType")
       .getFieldDefinition("field")
       .getDirective("custom_directive")
       .getArgument("url").getValue();

    value.get("address") //foo 
    value.get("description") //bar
```

You can also implement a `SchemaDirectiveWiring` and override its `onField()` which will be get called for the field marked with this directive 
during building `GraphQLSchema`. In this method, you can change this field 's `GraphQLFieldDefinition` based on the value configure in that directive. (e.g modifying its data fetcher etc.)

This `SchemaDirectiveWiring` is registered by the following when building `RuntimeWiring` :

```java
RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
.directive("custom_directive", new MySchemaDirectiveWiring())
.build();
```